# inserting image in database using php

Tags: php, database, image

I have problem with my code which is to insert image in the database using php the code worked great but when I connect it to the database I start to get an error.

**upload_image.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Uploading Images</title>
</head>
<body>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<form style="text-align:center" action="upload_image.php"  method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">

Select Image: <input type="file"    name="image"  >
<input type="submit"    name="upload"  value ="Upload Now">       
</form>
</body>

</html>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","name","pssword")or die(mysql_errno());
mysql_select_db("dbName")or die(mysql_errno());

$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))   

echo "please select an image";   

else 
{
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addcslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if($image_size == FALSE)
echo "this is not an image"; 
else
{
if (!$insert = mysql_query("insert into stores values('','$image_name',$image' )"))
echo "problem uploading image";
else 
{
{ 
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
echo "image uploaded. <p/> your image:<p/><img src=get_image.php?id=$last_id>";
}   
}
}
}
?>
```

**get_image.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","name","pssword")or die(mysql_errno());
mysql_select_db("dbName")or die(mysql_errno());

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
$image = mysql_query("select * from stores where id = $id");
$image= mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

This is the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\upload_image.php on line 30
```

Comment: Hi, this is a very common error message and Googling it (or searching on SO) will very quickly find you a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

I believe the error is being generated here because, when it isn't set, the `image` index is undefined (kapow!)

You could try this instead:

```
if ( ! isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    echo 'Please select a file..';
}
else
{
    // your code
}
```